# Getting server name (SNI) from pcap file with Python 3.4

Tags: python, pcap, sni

I am trying to analyze pcap file in order to verify that proper sni domain is applied.
My test automation tool - TestComplete - requires Python 3.4. 
Python's scapy_ssl_tls does not support Python3.

Googled a lot, but did not find anything like scapy_ssl_tls for python 3.4

Any suggestions?

P.S. I installed scapy_ssl_tls to Pytnon27, then copied it to Python34. 
While running from scapy_ssl_tls import * I get a warning: no module ssl_tls_registry. I tried to put it in all scapy related folders directly so it would be able to import it - no success.